# Python requests can't send multiple headers with same key

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a GET request to a server with two headers which have the same name, but different values:

```
url = 'whatever'
headers = {'X-Attribute': 'A', 'X-Attribute': 'B'}
requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

This obviously doesn't work, since the headers dictionary can't contain two keys `X-Attribute`.

Is there anything I can do, i.e. can I pass headers as something other than a dictionary?  The requirement to send requests in this manner is a feature of the server, and I can't change it.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The server I'm sending requests to expects it.  It filters responses based on the complete set of attributes passed to it, attributes are of the form `X-Attribute:name=value`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`requests` stores the request headers in a `dict`, which means every header can only appear once. So without making changes to the `requests` library itself it won't be possible to send multiple headers with the same name.

However, if the server is [HTTP1.1 compliant](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), it *must* be able to accept the same as one header with a comma separated list of the single values.

---

Late edit:
Since this was brought back to my attention, a way to make this work would be to use a custom instance of `str` that allows to store multiple of the same value in a `dict` by implementing the hash contract differently (or actually in a `CaseInsensitiveDict`, wich uses `lower()` on the names). Example:

```
class uniquestr(str):

    _lower = None

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other

    def lower(self):
        if self._lower is None:
            lower = str.lower(self)
            if str.__eq__(lower, self): 
                self._lower = self
            else:
                self._lower = uniquestr(lower)
        return self._lower

r = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", headers={uniquestr('X'): 'A',
                                                     uniquestr('X'): 'B'})
print(r.text)
```

Produces something like:

```
{
  ...
  "headers": {
    ...
    "X": "A,B",
  }, 
  ...
}
```

Interestingly, in the response the headers are combined, but they are really sent as two separate header lines.

Comment: That's useful to know.  Sadly, it doesn't look like the server is compliant!

Comment: I'd never suggest this as an answer, but you could try exploit the fact that requests doesn't automaticalle escape the content of the passed headers dict, and pass `headers={'X-Attribute': 'name=value\r\nX-Attribute: name=value'}`. It's not a very good solution however...

Comment: The workaround mentioned in the comment above doesn't work anymore since requests 2.11.0, as that introduced checking for return characters in header values. See: https://github.com/psf/requests/commit/2669ab797ce769ecedf5493b04cb976f33e37210

Comment: @Dunedan yea, that more or less only worked by using a bug in requests...

Answer (score 5):

requests is using urllib2.urlencode under the hood (or something similar) in order to encode the headers.

This means that a list of tuples can be sent as the payload argument instead of a dictionary, freeing the headers list from the unique key constraint imposed by the dictionary.  Sending a list of tuples is described in the urlib2.urlencode documentation.  http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

The following code will solve the problem without flattening or dirty hacks:

```
url = 'whatever'
headers = [('X-Attribute', 'A'),
           ('X-Attribute', 'B')]
requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for my version of requests (2.7.0).

Answer (score 3):

Requests now stores all headers (sent and received) as case insensitively in dictionaries. Beyond even that, though, open up a python console and write:

```
headers = {'X-Attribute':'A', 'X-Attribute':'B'}
```

What you get is undefined behaviour. (It may seem reproducible but it is wholly undefined.) So what you're really sending to requests in that instance is this:

```
{'X-Attribute': 'A'}  # or {'X-Attribute': 'B'}, we can never be certain which it will be
```

What you could try (but won't work) is:

```
headers = [('X-Attribute', 'A'), ('X-Attribute', 'B')]
```

But at least this will be wholly defined behaviour (you'll always send B). As @mata suggested, if your server is `HTTP/1.1` compliant, what you can do is this:

```
import collections

def flatten_headers(headers):
    for (k, v) in list(headers.items()):
        if isinstance(v, collections.Iterable):
           headers[k] = ','.join(v)

headers = {'X-Attribute': ['A', 'B', ..., 'N']}
flatten_headers(headers)
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I've seen that, in practice, HTTP servers tend to limit the lengths of header lines. What if the complete comma-separated list is too long for a line? That seems to require a solution to the original question.

Comment: @rspeer then you should tell that server's administrator that it isn't compliant. The best solution is to join them like so, for now. Because of the rarity of this case we do not have this feature as a high priority.

Answer (score 2):

```
url = 'whatever'
headers = {'X-Attribute': "A,B"}
requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

Comment: I've moved on from that project years ago, but I think you're suggesting exactly what @mata originally suggested...a compliant server is required to accept comma-separated values.  The server was non-compliant in many ways, including not accepted these.