# Can flask send duplicate headers in a response?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, http-headers

I would like my flask app to set multiple headers with the same key and different values, like this:

```
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

I already know that this is equivalent to a single header whose value is a comma-separated list (only for headers that support a list value, of course), but I would rather do it as above. But headers are stored in a dict, so I can't just add a duplicate key.

I am also aware of [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789840/python-requests-cant-send-multiple-headers-with-same-key), which says that the `requests` module cannot send multiple headers with the same key. But that question is about `requests`, and `flask` sometimes  has extra goodies; also the question is over seven years old, and things happen.

Is that answer up to date? Does it also apply to flask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Request Headers

You can have duplicated header keys, however, Flask turns them into a text, values separated with comma,

The easiest example would be:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(request.headers)
    return "Hello"
```

with the following `curl`:
`curl http://127.0.0.1:5000 -H 'X-HEADER: 1' -H 'X-HEADER: 2'`

Flask would print `X-Header: 1,2` for `X-Header` in headers
Also, you can get a list of values using `request.headers.getlist('X-Header')`, but it still sticks the values together and returns a list with only one element. `['1,2']`

The `request.headers` is an instance of `werkzeug.datastructures.EnvironHeaders`

Surely you can modify it to use your own headers class.
You can inherit `flask.Request` class and create your own `request` instance with customized `Headers` class

You can read more about `EnvironHeaders` here: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.EnvironHeaders

### Response Headers

About the response headers:

All flask responses come from `flask.Response` class.

You can return your response from your view like:

```
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return Response('Hello', headers={'X-Headers': [1, 2]})
```

You can test this with the following `curl`:
`curl http://127.0.0.1:5000 -vvv`
I added `-vvv` to increase verbosity and show Headers

The following will show up in response headers:

```
< X-Headers: 1
< X-Headers: 2
```

Also if you don't want to use `Response` class,
You can return multiple values from a view

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello!</h1>', 200, {'X-Headers': [1, 2]}
```

The first value is the body of your response, the second one is the status code, and the last one is the headers of your response.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm interested in the response header I generate from flask, not in the request itself -- I realize I wasn't very clear about this, sorry.